# Rails change two services with similar logic into one service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails6/Grape API app my controller starting to look a little bit heavy - there is a too much logic going so I wrap webhook distribution data into two services `Activities::WebhookData` and `Journeys::WebhookData` like below:

`endpoint`

```
post do
  name = CmsClient.fetch_model_name(model_id)
  #some other logic
  
  name == 'Journey' ? ::Journeys::WebhookData.new(params).call : ::Activities::WebhookData.new(params).call
end
```

`Journeys::WebhookData`

```
module Journeys
  class WebhookData
    def initialize(webhook)
      @webhook = webhook
    end

    attr_accessor :webhook

    def call
      case webhook[:event_type]
      when 'publish'
        JourneyWorker.perform_async(webhook)
      when 'delete'
        HideJourneyWorker.perform_async(webhook)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`Activities::WebhookData`

```
module Activities
  class WebhookData
    def initialize(webhook)
      @webhook = webhook
    end

    attr_accessor :webhook

    def call
      case webhook[:event_type]
      when 'publish'
        ActivityWorker.perform_async(webhook)
      when 'delete'
        DeleteActivityWorker.perform_async(webhook)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you see both are pretty much the same, is there a better way to merge these two services into one instead?

Comment: I think you've had a cut-and-paste error, because those are the exact same class.

Comment: @rmlockerd good catch! question updated

Comment: You should create a module with your functions and than use them using includes.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar what's the difference than current approach?

Answer (score 1):

I don't advice you to move that to a single class, because both classes have a different way to interpret the webhook data they receive. If you do so you're going to replace that with some if/else conditions.

You can create a class where you define the call method to fetch the values from a hash given the `event_type` in the attr_reader, then create two other classes inheriting from the first one and just define a hash of its own with the according classes where you're going to invoke `perform_async` on:

```
class Webhook
  def call
    event_types[webhook[:event_type]].public_send(:perform_async, webhook)
  end

  protected

  def initialize(webhook)
    @webhook = webhook
  end

  private

  attr_reader :webhook

  def event_types
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

module Journeys
  class WebhookData < Webhook
    def event_types
      { 'publish' => JourneyWorker, 'delete' => HideJourneyWorker }
    end
  end
end

module Activities
  class WebhookData < Webhook
    def event_types
      { 'publish' => ActivityWorker, 'delete' => DeleteActivityWorker }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why the `initialize` method is protected?

Comment: Because you don't need to initialize Webhook, but its inherited classes.